# clr stored procedure with SqlContext.Pipe.Send should return decimal, returns int

Tags: clr, decimal, return-value, pipe, clrstoredprocedure

I have a clr stored procedure that has to return decimal value.  I cannot use output parameters at this moment - i need to reuse the existing library that doesn't process output parameters.
My stored procedure returns a value - but it loosed decimal digits.
Any ideas why?
Thanks,
Jenny

```
[SqlProcedure]
public static int CalculateMyValue(SqlDecimal aInput1, SqlString aInput2, SqlDecimal aInput3)
{
    try
    {
        //convert second value to code.  call regular stored procedure
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("context connection=true");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_getCodeForVal", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyParam", aInput2);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        conn.Open();
        object input2CodeSql = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        conn.Close();

        if (input2CodeSql == null)
        {
            // debug print
            SqlContext.Pipe.Send(string.Format("aInput2 = {0}", aInput2));
            return 2;
        }

        decimal input2Code = Convert.ToDecimal(input2CodeSql.ToString());
        decimal input1Val = aInput1.Value;
        decimal input3Val = aInput3.Value;

        GetMyDecimal myVal = new GetMyDecimal();
        decimal decValue = myVal.Calculate(input1Val, input2Code, input3Val);
        //debug
        SqlContext.Pipe.Send(string.Format("decValue = {0}", decValue));

        // Create a record object that represents an individual row, including it's metadata.
        SqlDataRecord record = new SqlDataRecord(new SqlMetaData("decValue", SqlDbType.Decimal));

        // Populate the record.
        record.SetDecimal(0, decValue);

        // Send the record to the client.
        SqlContext.Pipe.Send(record);

        return 0;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

EDIT: forgot to add that SqlContext.Pipe.Send(string.Format("decValue = {0}", decValue));
shows decimal places but SqlContext.Pipe.Send(record); returns no decimal places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default decimal's precicion/scale is 18/0. Try using different overload for creating Meta Data:

```
SqlDataRecord record = new SqlDataRecord(new SqlMetaData("decValue", SqlDbType.Decimal, 19, 9, false, false, SortOrder.Ascending, 0));
```

Comment: @Boroda: Thank olli, not me. It's 100% his answer, I just edited it to make the code more readable, nothing more!